# Linux - specific API reference

Tags: linux, api

Where can I find centralized and complete documentation aboput Linux - specific API?

I'm preparing Linux port of my application and i want to use as much Linux - specific features as it's possible. So far I found that Linux provide epoll and inotify API, which are great news for me, because my program works as network server and monitor local file systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/

Comment: Great! Is there any overvire about Linux - specific API?